# Limiting MSI to Windows XP SP3 or SP2 for x64 with WiX

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to limit my MSI installer to work at least on Windows XP SP3 for x86 platforms, or on Windows XP SP2 for x64 platforms, or any later OS. I'm using WiX to do this with the following markup:

```
<Condition Message='Windows XP with Service Pack 3, or SP2 for 64-bit OS, or later OS is required.'>
<![CDATA[VersionNT > 501 OR (VersionNT = 501 AND ServicePackLevel = 3) OR (VersionNT64 = 501 AND ServicePackLevel = 2)]]></Condition>
```

But this doesn't seem to work when I try it on Windows XP SP1 for x64 platform.